# jQuery-File-Upload plugin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload

I am a Rails newbie.

I am trying to implement BlueImp's jQuery-File-Upload plugin into a Rails 4 app. So I have got basic file uploads working, but I'm having multiple problems. First of all, I'm getting a weird UI for the upload page.

I only see the Start Upload and Cancel Upload buttons. Even then, I can't click them because the invisible "Add Files" button is taking up half the page so I can only upload files by: clicking the huge, invisible "add files" button, choosing a file, pressing tab twice to highlight the Start Upload button and then pressing enter. Once uploaded, instead of going to any particular page, I go to a page that displays the parameters of the file upload. However, the file does upload. I would upload pictures but I apparently can't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the _form.html.haml file for the video_resources view. I think maybe the conversion from html to haml may be a problem.

```
= form_for VideoResource.new, :html => {:multipart => true, :id => "fileupdload" } do |f|
  .row.fileupload-buttonbar
    .span7
      %span.btn.btn-success.fileinput-button
        %i.icon-plus.icon-white
        %span Add files...
        = f.file_field :file_path
      %button.btn.btn-primary.start{:type => "submit"}
        %i.icon-upload.icon-white
        %span Start upload
      %button.btn.btn-warning.cancel{:type => "reset"}
        %i.icon-ban-circle.icon-white
        %span Cancel upload
      %button.btn.btn-danger.delete{:type => "button"}
        %i.icon-trash.icon-white
        %span Delete
      %input.toggle{:type => "checkbox"}/
    .span5
      .progress.progress-success.progress-striped.active.fade
        .bar{:style => "width:0%;"}
  .fileupload-loading
  %br/
  %table.table.table-striped
    %tbody.files{"data-target" => "#modal-gallery", "data-toggle" => "modal-gallery"}

:javascript
  var fileUploadErrors = {
    maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
    minFileSize: 'File is too small',
    acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
    maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
    uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
    emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
  };
/ The template to display files available for upload
%script#template-upload{:type => "text/x-tmpl"}
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-upload fade">
  <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
  <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
  <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
  {% if (file.error) { %}
  <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
  {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
  <td>
  <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
  </td>
  <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
  <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
  </button>
  {% } %}</td>
  {% } else { %}
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  {% } %}
  <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
  <button class="btn btn-warning">
  <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
  <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
  </button>
  {% } %}</td>
  </tr>
  {% } %}
/ The template to display files available for download
%script#template-download{:type => "text/x-tmpl"}
  {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-download fade">
  {% if (file.error) { %}
  <td></td>
  <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
  <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
  <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
  {% } else { %}
  <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
  <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
  {% } %}</td>
  <td class="name">
  <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
  </td>
  <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  {% } %}
  <td class="delete">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
  <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
  <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
  </button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
  </td>
  </tr>
  {% } %}
/ The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.widget.js'
/ The Templates and Load Image plugins are included for the FileUpload user interface
%script{:src => "http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"}
%script{:src => "http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"}
/ The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.iframe-transport.js'
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fileupload.js'
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fileupload-ui.js'
/ add include_tag js files to config.assets.precompile in ...environments/production.rb if you have it in vendor/ assets
%script{:charset => "utf-8", :type => "text/javascript"}
  $(function () {
  \// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
  $('#fileupload').fileupload();
  \//
  \// Load existing files:
  $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
  var fu = $('#fileupload').data('blueimp-fileupload'),
  template;
  fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
  template = fu._renderDownload(files)
  \.appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
  \// Force reflow:
  fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
  template[0].offsetWidth;
  template.addClass('in');
  $('#loading').remove();
  });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem like this as well and I had to include the Bootstrap CSS code correctly. However, I didn't actually want the Bootstrap library in my stylesheets as it's large and was interfering with my other styles, so I had to experiment a bit and pick out those styles which were actually effecting the buttons.

Here are some styles that I used that may get you started in the right direction. (This might not fix everything).

What I did to come to this was I referred to the page with the official demo: 
[https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/](http://jQuery%20File%20Upload%20Demo)

And then I opened up the Chrome Developer Tools and looked at what styles were being applied. The form input type to submit a file is actually hidden inside the Add Files button. This is a little awkward, but by design. The button is hidden because it's only used to hold the value of the file, whereas the form is submitted by the plugin's JavaScript. So what we want to do with that file input button is make it `position: absolute;` so that it doesn't distort other page elements. When uploaded using the plugin, the plugin will use AJAX instead of a direct form submit, and should not redirect you afterward. If after that, it's still not working, it may be the processing script on your server is misconfigured. I would need to see the code for that in more detail in order to help.

```
.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
} 
.fileinput-button {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.fileinput-button input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 200px;
    direction: ltr;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```